# Subscription Notifications in Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently implementing a Webhook with the Graph SDK and have a little problem/inconvenience. I am subscribing to calendar events of a user resource like this:

```
var request = GraphClientInitializer.Instance.GraphClient.Subscriptions.Request();
var result = await request.AddAsync(
                    new Subscription
                    {
                        ChangeType = WebhookConsts.SubscriptionChangeType,
                        NotificationUrl = WebhookConsts.SubscriptionNotificationUrl,
                        Resource = "/users/" + UserMail + "/" + "events",
                        ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                        ClientState = WebhookConsts.SubscriptionIdentifier
                    }
                    );
```

I receive notifiactions and i can read the messages sent to the notification url, but there doesn't seem to be an object in the SDK which parses received notifications.

Currently i am doing it myself:

```
public class Notification
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<NotificationValue> Values { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationValue
{
    [JsonProperty("subscriptionId")]
    public String SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subscriptionExpirationDateTime")]
    public String SubscriptionExpirationDateTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("clientState")]
    public String ClientState { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("changeType")]
    public String ChangeType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("resource")]
    public String Resource { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("resourceData")]
    public NotificationResourceData ResourceData { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationResourceData
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.type")]
    public String ODataType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@odata.id")]
    public String ODataId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("odata.etag")]
    public String ODataEtag { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public String Id { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an object i can use for this or any other way i can implement it in the Graph SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality does not currently exist in the SDK. The SDK is generated based on the metadata provided by the API service (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata) and the notification object is not defined there.

I believe this would make a great extension to the library. Would you be willing to open a pull request to the Microsoft.Graph `Models>Extensions` folder? This would allow others to make use of the notification class you've created.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Sure i can do that this evening. Pull requests should be done [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/pulls) right?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** This functionality was implemented in the PR [#1053](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/pull/1053) and now it is available through the class [ChangeNotificationCollection](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/d654ec8c55f5dd26eb76501e6820a49b9b48709e/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/ChangeNotificationCollection.cs#L21).

[image]